# JUnit Tests not running - Returning "Empty test suite"

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, junit

I'm just trying to run a simple get test in JUnit, with Spring:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

public class ProfileTest {

    @Autowired
    ProfileDAO dao;

    @Test
    public void getProfileTest() {
        dao.getProfile("John Doe")
    }
}
```

However, everytime I run it, it errors out with the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDefaultClassLoader()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.loadTestEngines(ServiceLoaderTestEngineRegistry.java:31)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:42)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.createListeners(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:39)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

Process finished with exit code 1
Empty test suite.
```

I've tried using File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart, but to no affect.  Based on further research, I think it's due to a version conflict between junit-jupiter-api and junit-command-commons.  Can anyone give me further direction?

Comment: So are you using Junit 4 or Junit 5?  Your runner says "4" but your error says "5".

Comment: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-ide

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.  I deleted the dependencies from the pom file for junit, junit-jupiter-api and junit-command-commons, and then just used junit, like so:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```